# Space between two entries in sharepoint list is too wide

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting

Please help me with the below requirement.
Space between two entries in sharepoint list is too wide. Below screenshot for your quick reference.

[image]

Comment: I think you have customized the list view using JSON formatting and that is what causing this issue. Can you please share the JSON code you have used. that might help to answer your question.

Comment: I have not used any JSON.

Comment: I can see you have color coded the columns (and maybe rows) and I believe for that JSON code is being used? How you have changed the background colors of columns? Are you using any multiple lines of text field in your list?

Comment: I have done the column formatting which is default in list setting.

Comment: Right. so you must have used JSON for that. Go to column settings --> format this column --> Advanced --> Copy paste the JSON. Also, I can see that 2nd row in your screenshot has green background color. have you used View formatting for that?

Comment: Yes, I have done the view formatting.

Comment: I have removed the formatting, but still the same

Comment: the data may be cached. trying clearing your browser cache

Comment: Have you removed both column and view formatting and the still the same error? or you have just removed one of view/column formatting? Also try hard refresh (Ctrl + F5) after removing formatting.

Comment: I have done the hard refresh, but still the same.

Comment: Create a new view and check that whether issue persists in new view as well.

Comment: Yes, try creating a new "standard" view and check if the problem stil exists.

Comment: still the issue is there.